# SwiftUI Document based multi - platform apps, saving content on iOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using the new multi platform document app template from Xcode 12.3.

The default template uses a TextEditor() to edit text. On macOS the text can be saved via manual save commands from the menu or keyboard shortcuts, on iOS the text is saved when clicking on the "<" symbol in the toolbar (before going back to the file browser).

Now, in my app I obviously do not use TextEditor() but I have my own editor logic. On macOS I can still manually save the project just fine, but on iOS when clicking on "<" the project will not be automatically saved anymore, i.e. the fileWrapper function in the FileDocument is not called.

I assume this is because nobody notified the system that the FileDocument changed ? But how todo that manually ?

Comment: If FileDocument is not marked as edited then most probably editing part lost binding to it. Would you show your code?

Comment: How can I set FileDocument as edited ? My general code is the same as the default template code, but the editor part is too complex to post here.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, all you need todo is to have a variable inside your document and change it, like

```
struct MyDocument: FileDocument {

    @ObservedObject var myProject = MyProject()
    var updated              : Bool = false
```

So every time I change myProject() I toggle the updated variable. I thought that sending objectWillChange() notifications to myProject will mark the project as edited, but it does not.

Comment: `@ObservedObject` is designed to be inside SwiftUI view, and meaningless outside, so I'd say this is incorrect model.

Comment: Ok thanks. I removed the @ObservedObject.